# Why does a motion detector provide enough power for an LED but not a class 2 transformer?

Tags: electrical, sprinkler-system

So I am a bit out of my league on this so I am looking for help.  I went to HD and bought a few things:

- Sprinkler Valve - Rain Bird
- [745407 Motion Detector](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Defiant-270-Degree-White-Replacement-Outdoor-Motion-Sensor-DF-5716-WH-C/203739886) (Used to turn on lights)
- 110vac 60Hz 23W to 24VAC 750 mA class 2 power supply
- indoor outdoor cord

I cut the cord and hooked it to the feed into the motion detector and then the used the female plug and hooked it up to the motion out wires.  The thing is if I hook a LED light to the plug the motion works great and turns on the light.  But, it seems that it is not enough juice to turn on the power supply.  I really did not think the power would be downgraded going through the motion detector but it seems like it must be.

I am trying to build my own motion activated sprinkler to scare off ducks from the dock.  Any one has any idea on the correct parts needed to make this happen would be wonderful.  They make them but they are cheap and don't last.  I was hoping to build one that would last and be 110 volt so no batteries would be needed.

Comment: Is the power supply literally a transformer, or is it an electronic power supply of some mind?  Is the motion detector a type which requires the neutral wire?

Comment: Sounds like you may have the motion detector wired wrong.  Did you check the wiring diagrams it came with?

Comment: @Harper -- the motion detector in question does hook up to the neutral, and a Class 2 transformer like his would indeed be a literal transformer as it's AC to AC

Comment: What model of sprinkler valve did you buy?

Comment: What happens if you hook up *both* the LED *and* the transformer?

Comment: I suspect you need more wattage.  To test, try temporarily putting a 3-way plug on the female end of your cord and plug in both an incandescent light (for more load) and your transformer.  I bet it work right with more load for tho motion sensor.   This assumes the motion is wired into the extension cord correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the electronics used by the motion detector modifies the since wave. Most power supplies today are switching supplies most will not function with a modified since wave. An old school transformer that steps the voltage down and a full wave bridge to change it to DC would do the job. I have a battery powered motion activated sprinkler close to my pool to scare ducks and geese away that has lasted for years with fresh batteries every few months. Like [this](http://www.domyownpestcontrol.com/scarecrow-sprinkler-motion-activated-animal-deterrent-p-3327.html?keyword=&gclid=Cj0KCQjwq7XMBRCDARIsAKVI5QZbFoEBTCudXimz-NU4DX36_3vjpLaqAgOYHpUxq7f_UviYaZDhWF8aAiLpEALw_wcB). Not an endorsement but the one I have is several years old and still works.